# Android permissions not requested after reinstall

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am testing my Android app on my own phone. When I first run it on my phone, it asks for permission to user my gmail account. When I reinstall my app, it no longer does that? I would like to make it so that it re-requests permission every time I reinstall the app for testing purposes. If, on the other hand, I change the package name, it re-requests the permission. Does anyone know how to do that? Much help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Note: By reinstall, I mean both pressing the run button and actually resinstalling the application by first uninstalling via settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an actual Android permission, it's actually an account access grant specific to AccountManager. Technically, when you uninstall an app all grants should be cleared, but this appears broken on some devices. If you have a rooted device or are using the emulator, you can find accounts.db (usually in `/data/system/users/0/accounts.db` on newer versions) and clear the grants and extras tables (that could affect other apps, so handle with care). If you don't, clearing the data for Google Account Manager and Google Play Services could help.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by reinstall? Does reinstall simply meaning pressing the "run" button? Or are you actually uninstalling and reinstalling the application. Once the Android OS detects that a permission is needed, it will request it from the user. But after that first time, it won't ask again. If you completely uninstall the application from the device and then reinstall, it should work. I don't know of any other way you can bypass that.

Comment: By reinstall, I mean both pressing the run button and actually resinstalling the application. I did completely reinstall the application via settings and it didn't work. The only time I got it to work was by changing the package name.